# Angularjs, select option after getting object from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*The short version of what I'm doing*:

I'm getting some JSON from the server to try to recreate the state of my form. Everything loads fine except for one select box that uses a function to get its display. How can I accomplish this?

*The longer version*:

I have a select box that looks like this:

```
<select name="size" ng-model="form.options.size" ng-options="form.displaySize(size) for size in form.sizes">
    <option disabled value="">-- choose dimensions --</option>
</select>
```

This works fine with the user selecting the option, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the select box to select the right size when `form.options.size` is set programmatically (after receiving some json from an api call).

My "size" object looks like this: `{width: (some width), length: (some length)}`.

My "displaySize" function just returns a string `width + "x" + length`.

I understand I could manually loop through the options and select the right one, but I'm really trying to avoid that as much as possible. What are my options?

**Edit:**
Fiddle showing exactly what I'm doing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fo1h1n53/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While assigning the value to the select model, the value assigned to the ng-model should have the reference in the json list given to the ng-options.

```
$scope.form.options.size = $scope.form.sizes[index];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptno0ew7/1/

OR

use track by option for the ng-options directive, updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fo1h1n53/1

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't know the index when I get the info back from the server. I've added a fiddle to my question showing more or less the exact circumstances.

Comment: use track by option for the ng-options directive, updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fo1h1n53/1/

Comment: Yes, track by did the trick! I used track by form.displaySize(size) and it worked!